# Kendo DataSource reading from Async/await method which uses Axios to fetch data

Tags: reactjs, axios, kendo-datasource, kendo-react-ui

Using **React** with **TypeScript**

Please could somebody provide an example of how I might be able to use a Kendo DataSource to read from a method which internally uses Axios to prod an external API for JSON data..? I must have flown through 20 different versions of this code trying different approaches, nothing seems to fit...

All I'm trying to do currently is supply a Kendo ComboBox with an array of {id: number, name: string}

Very basic stuff at the moment, but I do have to use a similar approach to this later on with a Kendo Grid which handles server side sorting and pagination so I'd like to get this working now then that should be somewhat easier later on...

The reason I want to use Axios is because I've written an api.ts file that appends appropriate headers on the gets and posts etc and also handles the errors nicely (i.e. when the auth is declined etc...)

A basic example of what I'm trying, which isn't working is this: -

```
public dataSource: any;

constructor(props: {}) {
super(props);

this.dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  type: "odata",
  transport: {
    read: function() {
      return [{ id: 1, name: "Blah" }, { id: 2, name: "Thing" }];
    }.bind(this)
  },
  schema: {
    model: {
      fields: {
        id: { type: "number" },
        name: { type: "string" }
      }
    }
  }
});
}

<ComboBox
   name="test"
   dataSource={this.dataSource}
   placeholder={this.placeholder}
   dataValueField="id"
   dataTextField="name"
/>
```

Anybody got any thoughts on this please? :)

Comment: The data source does have an endpoint option which you could provide. You do not wish to use that option?

Comment: @Icepickle You're suggesting the url: part of Transport? Doesn't this require an actual URL, therefore basically bypassing Axios..?

If that's the case then nope, because I'd have to individually handle the headers for auth and errors per datasource usage then..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy fix in the end...

```
this.dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
    read: function(options: any) {
      options.success([{ id: 1, name: "Blah" }, { id: 2, name: "Thing" }]);
    }.bind(this)
  },
  schema: {
    model: {
      fields: {
        id: { type: "number" },
        name: { type: "string" }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

2 things were wrong..

Removed the **type: "odata",**
and
Added the usage of **options** in

All working fine now with the async await function also, just passing the **data** into the **options.success** in the **.then** on the **promise**. Job done :-)